# UIButton(not working) on the UIImageView on the UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, ios, uibutton

I have `UIButton` on the `UIImageView` on the `UIScrollView`. However, button not working(Button does not respond　to it and wrote `button.userInteractionEnabled = YES`). Why?

```
pagingView = [[InfinitePagingView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.f, 0.f,            self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height - naviBarHeight)];
pagingView.delegate = self;
[self.view addSubview:pagingView];

UIImage *image1 = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"1.jpg"]];
page1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image1];
page1.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, pagingView.frame.size.width * 0.8, pagingView.frame.size.height * 0.8);
page1.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
page1.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
btn.frame = CGRectMake(100, 200, 50, 50);
[btn addTarget:self action:@selector(toControl) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[page1 addSubview:btn];
[pagingView addPageView:page1];
```

Comment: In what way is it not working? Can you post your code for the method `toControl`

Comment: It is visible buttons, but not push.

Comment: Log the frame width and height of the image view.

Comment: Button on the Image size 320x480.

Comment: what is addPageView??

Comment: Thank you kindly everyone.To give up, I'll make in a different way.

Comment: are you still trying the above way if yes then see my answer...

Comment: This all code in blog. http://goo.gl/ZJ90d

Answer (score 1):

Try to use following:

```
page1.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
btn.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

Also make sure your button is not out of ImageView's frame.
One more thing why don't you directly add your button to your view instead of your imageview.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (**tested**):

```
page1.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
btn.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

Comment: you can add gesture recognizer

Comment: I tried code(pagingView.userInteractionEnabled = YES, page1.userInteractionEnabled = YES, btn.userInteractionEnabled = YES)

Comment: can you send your sample? or add gesture recog.

Comment: Please tell me how to send my sample.

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
pagingView = [[InfinitePagingView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.f, 0.f,            self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height - naviBarHeight)];
pagingView.delegate = self;
[self.view addSubview:pagingView];

UIImage *image1 = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"1.jpg"]];
page1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image1];
page1.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, pagingView.frame.size.width * 0.8, pagingView.frame.size.height * 0.8);
page1.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
page1.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
[pagingView addPageView:page1];

btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
btn.frame = CGRectMake(100, 200, 50, 50);
[btn addTarget:self action:@selector(toControl) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[page1 addSubview:btn];
```